# How to sort a Dictionary by values in Smalltalk?

Tags: dictionary, smalltalk, pharo

I've got a Dictionary like this:

```
a PluggableDictionary(
    Rankable1->8.5
    Rankable2->9.0
)
```

I need just an OrderedCollection with the Rankable objects in descending order:

```
a OrderedCollection(
    Rankable2
    Rankable1
)
```

I noticed it is easy to sort by keys, but I found it a bit more difficult to sort by values. What is the smalltalk way of doing this?

Comment: i would ask, why you need sorting dictionary? you probably using wrong data structure for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need one shot sorted collection in noncritical loop you might use something like this (uses pharo syntax to initialize example dictionary):

```
pd := PluggableDictionary newFromPairs: { 'a' . 2 . 'b' . 1 . 'c' . 3} . 

(pd associations asSortedCollection: [:x :y | x value < y value]) 
            collect: [:assoc | assoc key].
```

If you would need it more often, than you might consider introducing your own class that will keep this collection calculated.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of method `asSortedCollection:`. Clearly, it is more readable. Thanks! PS: It should be `>` instead of `<`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VisualWorks, you can take advantage of SortFunction and Symbol>>value  behavior to reduce all of that down to

```
(aDictionary associations sort: #value ascending) collect: #key
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Grease (eg, when using Seaside), you can
probably use its `GROrderedMultiMap`. It is intended for small dictionaries with probably multiple values per key.

On a second note, probably you can swap key and value, and just send `#asSortedCollection`, like this:

```
(Dictionary newFrom: { 2 -> 'b' . 1-> 'a' }) 
    asSortedCollection "-->  a SortedCollection('a' 'b')"
```

(Tested in Squeak and Pharo)

Comment: Or just: (Dictionary newFrom: { 2 -> 'b' . 1-> 'a' }) sorted

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
^ ((SortedCollection sortBlock: 
   [:association :otherAssociation | association value > otherAssociation value])
   addAll: theDictionary associations;
   yourself) collect: [:association | association key]
```